# Playing with char array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, garbage

Is that safe to do something like this:

```
char* charArray = new char[10];  
strcat(charArray, "qwertyuiop");  
charArray[3] = '\0';  
delete [] charArray;
```

Will everything be deleted? Or that what is after `\0` won't be? I don't know if I'm leaving garbage.

EDIT: should be `strcpy`

Comment: make a ref to charArray[20] and see it value after delete[]

Comment: The call to strcat will result in Undefined Behaviour - after that all bets are off.

Comment: Paul R refers to the fact it is unknown where the first `\0` is in the memory where `charArray` is pointing, as `strcat`'s functionality depends on finding that.

Comment: @Eric: not only that, but even if the newly allocated `charArray` has a `\0` as its first character, strcat will write 11 characters to an array of size 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wanted to write `strcpy` instead of `strcat`, then that is safe and correct. But it seems you've a misconception about `delete [] charArray`. It doesn't delete characters, it deletes the memory pointed to by `charArray`. The memory even after `delete [] charArray` *might* contain those characters, it is not guaranteed though.

However, if you *really* wanted to write `strcat`, and it is not a typo, then your code invokes undefined behavior, because `charArray` contains garbage to which `strcat` will attempt to concatenate the second string.

Comment: It should be `strcpy` - typo.

Comment: The `strcat()` on an uninitialized array is certainly **not** fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Built-in types are not initialized like that. If you want to initialize it, then you've to write `new char[N]()`. Note the `()` in the new-expression.

Comment: The first statement in your answer is wrong. strcpy would be unsafe and incorrect as it would copy 11 bytes into a 10 byte array.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the fact that `new[]` for POD-types does not zero-initializes the array, and `strcat` would write the terminating `'\0'` past the end of the allocated area, everything looks fine: in particular, `delete` will delete the entire block.

The reason for writing past the end of the allocated block is that the 10-character string `"qwertyuiop"` requires 11 bytes to store.

Comment: `charArray` isn't initialized. `strcat` will be appending the word to garbage and will probably overwrite more than just the one byte. Behavior is undefined.

Comment: The objects are default initialized, but for primitive types that doesn't mean zero initialized. See [dcl.init] 8.5/6. The case that applies is "no initialization is performed".

Comment: @bames53 Very interesting! I re-read the spec, and it looks like the POD types are not default-initialized in the `new[]` operator. I edited the answer to reflect it, thanks.

Comment: Well, it is default initialized ([expr.new] 5.3.4/15) but ultimately that means that no initialization is performed on each element of the array ([dcl.init] 8.5/6).

Answer (score 3):

The `delete[]` releases the memory allocated after destroying the objects within (which diesn't do anything for `char`). It doesn't care about the content i.e. it will deallocate as many objects as were allocated.

Note that the use of `strcat()` depends on a null character to find the end of the string and that the memory returned from `new char[n]` is uninitialized. You want to start of with

```
*charArray = 0;
```

... and you might want to consider `strncat()` or, yet better, not use this at all but rather use `std::string`.

Comment: +1 for talking about (de)allocation instead of deletion (which is more precise, despite the name of the operator) and mentioning `std::string`, you're programming C++ after all. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, this is fine, the whole array is deleted. `delete` doesn't look at what the pointer you give it points to. As long as you match `new` with `delete`, and `new[]` with `delete[]`, the right amount of memory will be freed.

(But do consider using `std::string` instead of char arrays, that'll avoid a lot of bugs like the one you have there writing past the end of your array.)

Answer (score 2):

The `delete[]` statement does not know anything about what is stored in the buffer (including whether it is a string or not), so it will delete all 10 characters.  However, your `strcat` call is overflowing the end of the array (since C strings have a zero byte as terminator), which might break deletion on your platform and is not safe in general.